# Deploy Cloudfoundry app with Service (Spring Boot)

Tags: spring-mvc, cloud-foundry, spring-boot

I'm having a problem deploying an app with a service in cloudfoundry. It's been a week and i can't find a solution. Can you tell me guys whats wrong with my code? BTW, i can deploy without a service but when binding a service and trying to connect to the database hangs the deployment. I'm using spring sts in my deployment. I hope someone can help me figure this out.

this is my reference btw :
https://github.com/jwlayug/spring-cloud and https://github.com/jwlayug/spring-cloud/tree/master/spring-service-connector

My Code

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends AbstractCloudConfig {
    @Bean
    public DataSource inventoryDataSource() {
        return connectionFactory().dataSource("jwlpostgre");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

@Entity
class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    private String name;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }

}

interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

}

@Controller
class MyController {
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String sample(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("sample", "Sample");
        userRepository.save(new User("a"));
        userRepository.save(new User("b"));
        userRepository.save(new User("c"));
        model.addAttribute("findall", userRepository.findAll());
        for (User user : userRepository.findAll()) {
            System.out.println(user.getName());
        }
        return "sample";
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>springboot</name>
    <description>Demo project</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>org.springframework.maven.milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.3-1101-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-service-connector</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- If you intend to deploy the app on Cloud Foundry, add the following -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>cloudfoundry-connector</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <start-class>demo.Application</start-class>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't have more than one database datasource, you don't need to add that bean or name it.

make sure you exclude datasource auto config as this causes an issue.

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class) 
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

using the current versions worked for me.   Update to the latests and greatest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.gopivotal</groupId>
    <artifactId>redisstore</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>myapp</name>
    <description>myapp</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgres-driver.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-spring-service-connector</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <!-- Transitively bring in the Spring IO Platform Bill-of-Materials `pom.xml` -->    
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

<repositories>
 <repository>
       <id>org.springframework.maven.milestone</id>
       <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
       <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
     </repository>
</repositories>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>com.mycompany.myapp.Application</start-class>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <postgres-driver.version>9.0-801.jdbc4</postgres-driver.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring Cloud's AbstractCloudConfig implements BeanFactoryAware, and it does some bean lookups/additions. I think having your Application class extend from AbstractCloudConfig is causing problems with the order of application context creation and refreshing. Try moving the dataSource @Bean method out of Application and into a separate @Configuration class.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is you have an older version on Spring Cloud and it isn't binding because the environment variable format changed. Or it could be that you actually don't have a database with that identifier. (The Spring Cloud project is [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-cloud) by the way - the links you referenced are from a fork.)

Comment: i tried updating my cloudfoundry-connect and spring-service-connector to 0.9.8(latest) and im sure about the name of my service jwlpostgre
. It still hangs on deployment.

Comment: "Hangs" doesn't really tell us very much (and nothing hangs for very long with cloudfoundry because it is all goverened by timeouts). Do you have logs?