# Off Platform Sybase connection using Spring Boot and Cloud Foundry

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, sybase, cloud-foundry

I am trying to create an off-platform sybase connection in my application.
I am using Spring boot and have also created a user provided service at CF.
what extension classes would I need to create or use to achieve this ?
I have done oracle connection using OracleServiceInfo and  OracleServiceInfoCreator class.
but there is no SybaseServiceInfo class.

Below are the details for the ups

```
{
   "credentials": {
     "hostname": "host",
     "jdbcUrl": "jdbc:sybase://username:password@host:port/name",
     "name": "name",
     "password": "password",
     "port": "port",
     "uri": "sybase://username:password@host:port/name",
     "username": "username"
   },
   "label": "user-provided",
   "name": "SYBDB",
   "syslog_drain_url": "",
   "tags": []
 }
```

I am new to CF. Any help would be great.

After looking into Scott Fredrick's reply I took below mentioned steps :

I have created a ServiceInfoCreator class and a ServiceInfo class as mentioned below:

ServiceInfoCreator

```
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.cloud.cloudfoundry.CloudFoundryServiceInfoCreator;
import org.springframework.cloud.cloudfoundry.Tags;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;

@Profile({ "cloud" })
public class SybaseServiceInfoCreator extends
        CloudFoundryServiceInfoCreator<SQLDBServiceInfo> {

    public SybaseServiceInfoCreator(Tags tags, String[] uriSchemes) {
        super(new Tags(), "sybase");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public SQLDBServiceInfo createServiceInfo(Map<String, Object> serviceData) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String, String> credentials = (Map<String, String>) serviceData
                .get("credentials");

        String id = serviceData.get("name").toString();
        String uri = credentials.get("uri");


        return new SQLDBServiceInfo(id, uri);
    }


}
```

ServiceInfo

```
import org.springframework.cloud.service.UriBasedServiceInfo;

public class SQLDBServiceInfo extends UriBasedServiceInfo {

    public SQLDBServiceInfo(String id, String uriString) {
        super(id, uriString);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }




}
```

and I made an entry in META-INF/Services/org.springframework.cloud.cloudfoundry.CloudFoundryServiceInfoCreator

```
com.x.y.SybaseServiceInfoCreator
```

but I get the below error when I push the application :

```
2015-04-20T16:28:59.85+0530 [App/0]   ERR       ... 190 more
2015-04-20T16:28:59.85+0530 [App/0]   ERR Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.C
loud]: Factory method 'cloud' threw exception; nested exception is java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.springframework.cloud.CloudConnector: Provider or
g.springframework.cloud.cloudfoundry.CloudFoundryConnector could not be instantiated
2015-04-20T16:28:59.85+0530 [App/0]   ERR       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrat
egy.java:189)
2015-04-20T16:28:59.85+0530 [App/0]   ERR       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorRes
olver.java:588)
2015-04-20T16:28:59.85+0530 [App/0]   ERR       ... 202 more
2015-04-20T16:28:59.85+0530 [App/0]   ERR Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.springframework.cloud.CloudConnector: Provider org.springframew
ork.cloud.cloudfoundry.CloudFoundryConnector could not be instantiated
2015-04-20T16:28:59.85+0530 [App/0]   ERR       at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
2015-04-20T16:28:59.85+0530 [App/0]   ERR       at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
2015-04-20T16:28:59.85+0530 [App/0]   ERR       at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
2015-04-20T16:28:59.85+0530 [App/0]   ERR       at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
2015-04-20T16:28:59.85+0530 [App/0]   ERR       at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
2015-04-20T16:28:59.85+0530 [App/0]   ERR       at org.springframework.cloud.CloudFactory.scanCloudConnectors(CloudFactory.java:91)
2015-04-20T16:28:59.85+0530 [App/0]   ERR       at org.springframework.cloud.CloudFactory.<init>(CloudFactory.java:35)
2015-04-20T16:28:59.85+0530 [App/0]   ERR       at com.x.y.config.CloudAdminConfig.cloud(CloudAdminConfig.java:56)
2015-04-20T16:28:59.85+0530 [App/0]   ERR       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2015-04-20T16:28:59.85+0530 [App/0]   ERR       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2015-04-20T16:28:59.85+0530 [App/0]   ERR       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2015-04-20T16:28:59.85+0530 [App/0]   ERR       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
2015-04-20T16:28:59.85+0530 [App/0]   ERR       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrat
egy.java:162)
2015-04-20T16:28:59.85+0530 [App/0]   ERR       ... 203 more
2015-04-20T16:28:59.85+0530 [App/0]   ERR Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.springframework.cloud.cloudfoundry.CloudFoundryServiceInfoCreat
or: Provider com.x.y.config.SybaseServiceInfoCreator could not be instantiated
2015-04-20T16:28:59.85+0530 [App/0]   ERR       at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
2015-04-20T16:28:59.85+0530 [App/0]   ERR       at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
2015-04-20T16:28:59.85+0530 [App/0]   ERR       at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
2015-04-20T16:28:59.85+0530 [App/0]   ERR       at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
2015-04-20T16:28:59.85+0530 [App/0]   ERR       at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
2015-04-20T16:28:59.86+0530 [App/0]   ERR       at org.springframework.cloud.AbstractCloudConnector.scanServiceInfoCreators(AbstractCloudConnector.java:53)
2015-04-20T16:28:59.86+0530 [App/0]   ERR       at org.springframework.cloud.AbstractCloudConnector.<init>(AbstractCloudConnector.java:33)
2015-04-20T16:28:59.86+0530 [App/0]   ERR       at org.springframework.cloud.cloudfoundry.CloudFoundryConnector.<init>(CloudFoundryConnector.java:32)
2015-04-20T16:28:59.86+0530 [App/0]   ERR       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
2015-04-20T16:28:59.86+0530 [App/0]   ERR       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
2015-04-20T16:28:59.86+0530 [App/0]   ERR       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
2015-04-20T16:28:59.86+0530 [App/0]   ERR       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
2015-04-20T16:28:59.86+0530 [App/0]   ERR       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:438)
2015-04-20T16:28:59.86+0530 [App/0]   ERR       at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
2015-04-20T16:28:59.86+0530 [App/0]   ERR       ... 213 more
2015-04-20T16:28:59.86+0530 [App/0]   ERR Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.x.y.config.SybaseServiceInfoCreator
2015-04-20T16:28:59.86+0530 [App/0]   ERR       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:423)
2015-04-20T16:28:59.86+0530 [App/0]   ERR       at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
2015-04-20T16:28:59.86+0530 [App/0]   ERR       ... 224 more
2015-04-20T16:28:59.86+0530 [App/0]   ERR Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.x.y.config.SybaseServiceInfoCreator.<init>()
2015-04-20T16:28:59.86+0530 [App/0]   ERR       at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3074)
2015-04-20T16:28:59.86+0530 [App/0]   ERR       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:408)
2015-04-20T16:28:59.86+0530 [App/0]   ERR       ... 225 more
2015-04-20T16:29:02.38+0530 [DEA]     OUT Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2015-04-20T16:29:02.39+0530 [API]     OUT App instance exited with guid e946c9db-afdc-459a-bd01-ff718a5900db payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>
"e946c9db-afdc-459a-bd01-ff718a5900db", "version"=>"aeb7dbc8-e856-445b-80f1-0ff56339e1f5", "instance"=>"3efe1b541e2a4c6eb6aaecd7daac1143", "index"=>0, "reaso
n"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"app instance exited", "crash_timestamp"=>1429527542}
```

Not sure what I am messing up.

There's also a warning that it cannot find the ServiceInfoCreator in the beginning

```
2015-04-20T18:04:59.98+0530 [App/0]   OUT 2015-04-20 12:34:59.988  WARN 33 --- [           main] o.c.r.o.s.cloud.AbstractCloudConnector   : No suitable servi
ce info creator found for service SYBDB Did you forget to add a ServiceInfoCreator?
```

Comment: Check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23272580/deploy-cloudfoundry-app-with-service-spring-boot.

Comment: Your `SybaseServiceInfoCreator` class must have a no-args constructor, similar to the one here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-connectors/blob/master/spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/cloudfoundry/MysqlServiceInfoCreator.java#L12-L15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Spring Cloud Connectors](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-connectors) is the project that provides the `OracleServiceInfo` and `OracleServiceInfoCreator` classes that you mentioned. As you've said, Spring Cloud Connectors doesn't support Sybase database connections. So, you have two choices:

1) Extend Spring Cloud Connectors to support Sybase connections via a user-provided service. Documentation on writing such an extension can be found [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-connectors/tree/master/spring-cloud-core#adding-service-discovery) and [here](http://www.slideshare.net/ramnivas2/spring-one2014-springcloudconnector). These extension classes can be in your project or in a separate library, they don't need to be a part of the core SCC project for you to use them.

2) Use the `vcap` properties that Spring Boot automatically adds to the environment when it detects that an app is running on Cloud Foundry. You could do something as simple as including a `@Value("${vcap.services.sybase.credentials.jdbcUrl}")` annotation on a Spring bean and use that value to create a `DataSource` bean. See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/cloudfoundry/VcapApplicationListener.html) for more details.

The second choice is far simpler, and is a good place to start. If you just have one application that will use this type of connection then this might suffice. If you need to use this type of connection in multiple apps then writing the SCC extension in the first option and making that a re-usable library would be a better option.

Comment: Updated my question after starting with the first approach you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.That seemed to be the problem. 
This is how I created my classes now 
ServiceInfoCreator

```
@Profile({ "cloud" })
public class SybaseServiceInfoCreator extends
        RelationalServiceInfoCreator<SybaseServiceInfo> {

    public SybaseServiceInfoCreator() {
        super(new Tags(), "sybase");
        }

    @Override
    public SybaseServiceInfo createServiceInfo(String id, String uri) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return new SybaseServiceInfo(id, uri, "sybase");
    }

    }
```

ServiceInfo

```
@Profile({ "cloud" })
@ServiceInfo.ServiceLabel("sybase")
public class SybaseServiceInfo extends RelationalServiceInfo {

     public SybaseServiceInfo(String id, String url, String uri) {
            super(id, validateUrl(url), uri);
        }
        private static String validateUrl(String url) {
            if (parse(url).getHost() == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The URL " + url
                        + " does not appear to contain a hostname - are you missing a trailing slash?");
            }

            return url;
        }

        private static URI parse(String url) {
            try {
                return new URI(url);
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String getJdbcUrl() {
            return String.format("jdbc:%s:Tds:%s:%d/%s",
                    jdbcUrlDatabaseType,getHost(), getPort(), getPath());
        }


}
```